# Schedule Rails Task to run at a certain time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks

I'm currently creating a rails application and would like to find out how to schedule certain tasks to run at a specific time.

For e.g. An admin would want to send emails to his users at 8:00am in the morning and does not want to wake up early just to send that email. Therefore, he/she would want to schedule the task to send emails at that time.

So, is there a way, or better still a gem, that allows tasks to be scheduled to run at a specific time? Thanks!

Comment: Can active job do the same thing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My preferred solution here is the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

With it, you have `schedule.rb` file, which specifies when certain things should be done, including running rake tasks, executing methods, or even executing arbitrary shell commands:

Example schedule.rb file, shamelessly copied from the Whenever readme:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end

every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "SomeModel.ladeeda"
end

every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do # Use any day of the week or :weekend, :weekday
  runner "Task.do_something_great"
end

every '0 0 27-31 * *' do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end

# run this task only on servers with the :app role in Capistrano
# see Capistrano roles section below
every :day, :at => '12:20am', :roles => [:app] do
  rake "app_server:task"
end
```

I use Whenever for a number of tasks, including sending daily emails.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to create a tasks file to store the method or can I just add the method in the schedule.rb file? For example, I want to call a certain method every minute, can I just type "every 1.minute do ........ end" ?

Comment: @user192249 You don't need any special file besides schedule.rb - although I do make all my tasks into class methods on one or another class. Just call them using `runner`, as above.